# OpenCv internal function "contourArea" error

Tags: python, opencv

I'm fairly new to coding and trying to get into computer vision. I downloaded some code directly from github to start playing around with it, but I can't get it to run for some reason. I installed all the modules required via pip, and cv2 imports at the beginning of the code just fine. Whenever it gets to one of the internal functions, it errors out though on this line.

```
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
```

Yields the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nikolaipeterson/Desktop/hairline_detection-master/source.py", line 59, in <module>
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:272: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'contourArea'
```

I'd really appreciate any help. I got the code from https://github.com/miramind/hairline_detection

Comment: The error says that what you pass to the function does not have any points or is in another type that is not int or float. Whats the `len(cnts)`? and the len of each of the things in cnts? whats the dtype of each of the arrays in cnts?

Comment: The len(cnts) is 1. For more context, the code appears after a findContours line. These contours are numpy arrays.                                                                      
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
cnt=cnts[0]
topmost = tuple(cnt[cnt[:,:,1].argmin()][0])

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in Opencv4 `cv2.findContour()` only returns 2 values: `contours, hierachy` https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html.

So it should be

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
```